# Re-upgrading the same content database SharePoint 2013 upgrade

Tags: 2013, upgrade, content-database

I have a question more than an issue, I have a  scenario where I perform a database attach content DB migration and this works out OK, then the site goes into a period of UAT and after a week or so the customer would like to do this again for the production server. I then take another backup of the content database and attach it to the 2013 farm and upgrade it again (after discarding the original tested and upgraded DB).

So then I upgrade again with Mount-SPContentDatabase and it goes off and upgrades again, this seems to all work out in the test environment but perhaps I'm missing something here such as references in the SharePoint_Config DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if there is anything more to upgrading your content databases in its entirety, as long as there are no custom solutions (those need to be migrated), then you should be able to just run the content database upgrade procedure which will point to a web application and the site mapping/structure will be the same as it was in the previous version.

Comment: I ran this through on my test environment and since the web app has all the custom solutions etc installed already it was a matter of discarding the already upgraded DB and re-upgrading the same 2010 content DB and re-running the site collection upgrade with the same result as the first attempt. I'm planning on using this method to allow the customers to do UAT on the 2013 farm, once they're happy / worked out issues then re-upgrading the 2010 content database on the 2013 farm will commence for production